# Working with Gmail API from Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail-api

In GAE standard environment, I'm struggling with registering the `watch()` call against Gmail API for the Pub/Sub push notification using `google-api-python-client`.

Here is the relevant excerpt from my code:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
from oauth2client import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '<My-project>-<short-ID>.json'

credentials = service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
gmail = googleapiclient.discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

watchRequest = {
    'labelIds' : ['INBOX'],
    'topicName' : 'projects/<my-project>/topics/<my-topic>'
}

gmail.users().watch(userId='<email-I-need-to-watch>', body=watchRequest).execute()
```

After firing-off this part of the code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File     "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in     _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~<my-project>-191008/20180124t154459.407164278206739455/main.py", line 68, in <module>
gmail.users().watch(userId='<email-I-need-to-watch>', body=watchRequest).execute()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~<my-project>/20180124t154459.407164278206739455/lib/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~<my-project>/20180124t154459.407164278206739455/lib/googleapiclient/http.py", line 844, in execute
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/<email-I-need-to-watch>/watch?alt=json returned "Bad Request">
```

In regards to the authentication and authorization, here is what I have done so far:

1. I've created a Pub/Sub topic and this is the one I'm passing into the `watch()` request
2. I use G-Suite and the email inbox I intend to watch is part of my G-Suite business domain.
3. For this task I use a service account with enabled G-Suite Domain-wide Delegation. I've downloaded the .json service account file which I'm supplying in order to acquire the `oauth2client.service_account.Credentials` object (I see the access and refresh tokens being exchanged successfully in the logs). The json service file is placed in the same folder as my `main.py` script (root of my project).
4. In my G-Suite administration panel I've enabled the api access to the service account from 2. with the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify`. I'm using the `gmail.modify` access level as I intend to read, write and send both emails and drafts.

Is there something I'm missing out in my code or in the authentication and authorization steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. I was missing the part of the code for impersonating a user from my domain in order to read his/her mailbox (as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts)).

The corrected code looks like this:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES
)
credentials = credentials.with_subject('<email-I-need-to-watch>')

gmail = googleapiclient.discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

watchRequest = {
    'labelIds' : ['INBOX'],
    'topicName' : 'projects/<my-project>/topics/<my-topic>'
}

gmail.users().watch(userId='me', body=watchRequest).execute()
```